# Wordpress/CSS: Force a class that inherit from another

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to force an element that is part of a class in order to behave differently from the other elements, but when I try to change the color, for example, it doesn't work (see picture below). I tried using "!Important" with no success.

The element is in a "li":

```
<li id="menu-item-178" class="logo-site menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-178"><a title="Home" href="/">Home</a></li>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target your CSS in a more specific manner:

```
.logo-site a[title="home"] { 
  color: #fff;
}
```

See: https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/